# Oracle: Materialized view log not being cleared after commit

Tags: sql, database, oracle, materialized-views

I have a number materialized view logs which are not clearing themselves after commit. How do I find out why these logs are not clearing themselves on commit?

Comment: are you talking about undo logs?

Comment: pease update the question if you mean "after successfull refresh"

Comment: did you resolved the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You imply that your MV's were created to refresh ON COMMIT, but is that really the case? When are the MV's refreshed? ON COMMIT, ON DEMAND, or on some sort of refresh schedule? Fast refresh is not synonymous with ON COMMIT, it just means an incremental refresh as opposed to a full refresh.

Comment: They are FAST REFRESH and ON COMMIT.

Answer (score 0):

I understand it is not your case, but in case the MVlog is not cleared after refresh on demand:

If the base table and MV are in different version of ORACLE(ie source is 11g and dest is 10g), they would have problem to register(if I exactly recall) and there are situations when it does not delete de MV after refresh(It happened to me, I truncated the MVlogs until the upgrade of source database).